# SensoMineR panelperf error in contrasts , contrasts can only be applied to factors with 2 or more levels

Tags: r, factors, levels, contrast

I am trying to run the following code using the panelperf function from the SensoMineR package:

`panelperf<-panelperf(data,formul="~Product+Panelist+rep+Product:Panelist+Product:rep+Panelist:rep", firstvar=4)`

My data frame consists on: column 1: panelists, filled with names of panelists
column 2: product: filled with the names of the products
column 3: rep , the replicate of the product measured
column 4 till the end: variables that were measured (light fruit, dark fruit, alcohol, sourness, etc)
All my variables are dbl

But I get the following error when running the function:
`` Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels In addition: Warning messages: 1: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames 2: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames 3: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames ``

`sapply(lapply(data, unique), length)`

```
   Product     Panelist          rep   Lightfruit    Darkfruit    Applepear       Citrus     DryFruit        Nutty   Vegetables       Earthy       Floral 
        13           12            2           87           83           72           67           76           69           76           67           66 
     Woddy          hgt     Chemical    Chocolate        Honey       Cheesy      Alcohol Overallaroma   Astringent         Sour          Hot    Viscocity 
        62           64           80           57           65           69           86           85           88           85           85           83 
     Sweet       Bitter 
        87           86 
So none of the variables has only 2 levels as the error suggests
I have been reading answers about this error, but either the answers dont apply to my case or, as a non very experienced R user, I do not follow what they suggest. 

I would appreciate your help a lot!
Thank you!

And let me know if you need more information!
```

Answer (score 0):

The code to check the factor levels can be

```
i1 <- sapply(data, \(x) is.factor(x) && nlevels(x) > 1)
i2 <- !sapply(data, is.factor)
data1 <- data[i1|i2]
```

---

Here is an example that shows the issue - with the data having nlevels for factor > 1, it works

```
library(SensoMineR)
data(chocolates)
res <- panelperf(sensochoc, firstvar = 5, formul = "~Product+Panelist+
    Session+Product:Panelist+Session:Product+Panelist:Session")
> str(res)
List of 4
 $ p.value    : num [1:14, 1:6] 8.85e-14 6.44e-08 1.75e-28 3.74e-40 1.18e-22 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:14] "CocoaA" "MilkA" "CocoaF" "MilkF" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "Product         " "Panelist        " "Session         " "Product:Panelist" ...
 $ variability: num [1:14, 1:6] 0.139 0.103 0.397 0.532 0.267 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:14] "CocoaA" "MilkA" "CocoaF" "MilkF" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "Product         " "Panelist        " "Session         " "Product:Panelist" ...
 $ res        : num [1:14, 1] 1.87 1.89 1.41 1.47 1.63 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:14] "CocoaA" "MilkA" "CocoaF" "MilkF" ...
  .. ..$ : chr "stdev residual"
 $ r2         : num [1:14, 1] 0.673 0.761 0.846 0.882 0.862 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:14] "CocoaA" "MilkA" "CocoaF" "MilkF" ...
  .. ..$ : chr "r2"
 > str(sensochoc)
    'data.frame':   348 obs. of  18 variables:
     $ Panelist   : Factor w/ 29 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
     $ Session    : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ Rank       : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 6 3 5 2 4 1 4 3 5 ...
     $ Product    : Factor w/ 6 levels "choc1","choc2",..: 6 3 2 1 4 5 4 3 6 2 ...
     $ CocoaA     : int  7 6 8 7 8 7 6 4 5 5 ...
     $ MilkA      : int  6 7 6 8 5 5 1 2 1 2 ...
     $ CocoaF     : int  6 2 5 8 4 3 8 3 8 8 ...
     $ MilkF      : int  5 7 4 3 4 5 1 4 1 1 ...
     $ Caramel    : int  5 8 7 3 4 6 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ Vanilla    : int  3 4 4 2 4 2 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ Sweetness  : int  7 7 5 4 5 5 1 5 1 0 ...
     $ Acidity    : int  2 2 5 7 6 4 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ Bitterness : int  4 2 6 8 6 7 3 0 3 6 ...
     $ Astringency: int  5 3 6 6 4 4 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ Crunchy    : int  8 3 7 3 6 6 8 4 6 8 ...
     $ Melting    : int  3 8 5 2 3 6 5 8 2 2 ...
     $ Sticky     : int  4 6 4 3 7 4 0 3 1 4 ...
     $ Granular   : int  3 5 3 5 3 7 0 1 1 0 ...
```

If we change the 'Session' level 2 to NA (which have only 2 levels), it shows the error

```
levels(sensochoc$Session)[2] <- NA

res1 <- panelperf(sensochoc, firstvar = 5, formul = "~Product+Panelist+
        Session+Product:Panelist+Session:Product+Panelist:Session")
 Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
   contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

With OP's code, it still shows the data to be having more than 1 level because `unique` returns `NA` as well if present and thus the `length` will include the NA element, here it is 2 in total

```
> sapply(lapply(sensochoc, unique), length)
   Panelist     Session        Rank     Product      CocoaA       MilkA      CocoaF       MilkF     Caramel     Vanilla   Sweetness     Acidity 
         29           2           6           6          11          11          11          11          11          10          11          11 
 Bitterness Astringency     Crunchy     Melting      Sticky    Granular 
         11          11          11          11          11          11
```

where as with the  specific code in this post, `nlevels` remove the `NA` an return only the count of non-NA levels

```
i1 <- sapply(sensochoc, \(x) is.factor(x) && nlevels(x) > 1)
i2 <- !sapply(sensochoc, is.factor)
names(sensochoc)[i1]
[1] "Panelist" "Rank"     "Product" 
names(sensochoc)[sapply(sensochoc, is.factor)]
[1] "Panelist" "Session"  "Rank"     "Product"
```

`Session` is omitted.  We may need to change the formula to omit the terms that have `Session`

Comment: Hello Akrun! Thank you for your answer. Nevertheless, I am not sure how that helps me to fix my problem. I have already checked and using the sapply function as I copied in the post and all my factors have 2 or more levels. .